# downloading games on windows phone on wifi

Tags: microsoft-account

While on wifi, can you download games and apps on a prepaid windows phone that does not have a data plan? The person that set my phone up put my email address in as the primary. I think they should have put a Hotmail or outlook address in.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you have the phone set up with a valid Microsoft account, yes. You should be able to download apps while on Wi-Fi.